# How to change host_name in Conan io server before launch the container?

Tags: c++, conan

I am running  [conan io](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/uploading_packages/running_your_server.html#server-parameters)  server in a docker container. I am trying to access the server from another docker container. Both containers are running on same network. As far as I understood from documentation I have to change in server.conf file
`host_name : localhost` to `host_name: machineIP` before container start. So far I got it, but I don't know how to change configuration before I launch the container.

```
[server]

ssl_enabled: False
port: 9300
public_port: 9999
host_name: localhost
```

I see server configuration afterward, when I interacting with container. I have to some how override default configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the issue but I am not sure whether the solution good is. I create a custom configuration file and add to the corresponding path in dockerfile.